# Azure APIM cache-lookup policy error fallback

Tags: azure, caching, policy, apim

I implemented a `cache-lookup` policy in my API instance using internal cache and it's working fine.

However, I noticed this red flag in the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache):

> if the cache-related operations fail to connect to the cache due to the volatility of the cache or any other reason, the API call that uses the cache related operation doesn't raise an error, and the cache operation completes successfully. In the case of a read operation, a null value is returned to the calling policy expression. Your policy code should be designed to ensure that there's a "fallback" mechanism to retrieve data not found in the cache

How should I handle that? Is the mentioned `null` value set in the response body so I can easily use a `when` condition to change the status code in the fallback path?

I wrote this code but I don't know how to simulate the "connection error", so I still don't know if it does work or not:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="internal" />

        <!-- this is a mock for testing -->
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://run.mocky.io/v3/redacted" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="originalResponseBody" value="@(context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true))" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables["originalResponseBody"] == null)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="500" reason="Error" />
                    <set-body>{
                            "error": "Returning null"
                        }</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <cache-store duration="1800" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I would like to keep my policy simple as it should be for a simple cache lookup - so I exclude to use a custom caching system like `cache-lookup-value` ([too complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key) to manage in my opinion).

Anyone has faced this issue before?

Comment: are you getting any error while executing this policy?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Not in the actual one with a simple `cache-lookup` and `cache-store` ([this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache))

Comment: Can you please share the policy where you are getting the error and also share the error message

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I'm not hitting any error. As I said in my original post, policy is working fine. However, the documentation I linked says that the policy might fails without raising an exception, giving back `null` as result. A path pretty hard to reproduce and test and poor documented (is the body null or something else?)